# Bash script invoked by "mpirun" calls another MPI executable and crashes with exit code 13

Tags: sh, mpi, exit-code

I have two executables: `prog1` and `prog2`.

These executables read input data and then do some calculations on it. Depending on the "type" of input data, either `prog1` or `prog2` have to be used.

I would like to simplify this for the user who should just have to call `prog`, which is a shell script that

1. checks on the data (by running `prog1`),
2. runs `prog1` or `prog2` with `exec`.

For serial programs (no MPI), this works well. In the case of MPI, I want to call `prog` with `mpirun -n 2 prog`. Then, the shell script is invoked by the two processes. This fails if step (1) involves running another MPI executable.

A simple solution would be to compile a serial version of `prog1` (for step 1) and use this version instead. However, it would be much simpler for me if I could just use the MPI executable that I already have.

Below, I give a very simple testcase.

---

I have found similar questions on the internet, but none really helped me.

The closest one is from an Intel forum:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-clusters-and-hpc-technology/topic/754976
(unfortunately with no replies)

This is a minimal MPI program (`run.f90`):

```
program run

use mpi

implicit none

integer::num_process,rank,ierr;

call MPI_Init(ierr);
call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank,ierr);
call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, num_process,ierr);

write(*,*) 'I am',rank

call MPI_Finalize(ierr);

end program
```

This is a simple serial program (`simple.f90`)

```
program test
implicit none
write(*,*) 'hello'
end
```

This is a simple shell script (`script.sh`) that first gets some data from `simple` or `run` and then executes `run`

```
#!/bin/sh
#data=`simple` # this works
data=`run` # this does not work
echo "exec run..."
exec run
```

Compilation:

```
mpiifort run.f90 -o run
mpiifort simple.f90 -o simple
```

Run `script.sh` through `mpirun`:

The command `mpirun -n 2 script.sh` fails with

```
exec run...
exec run...

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 21258 RUNNING AT iff822
=   EXIT CODE: 13
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Broken pipe (signal 13)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

With `simple` instead of `run` in `script.sh`, the command `mpirun -n 2 script.sh` works

```
exec run...
exec run...
 I am           1
 I am           0
```

Comment: Try `mpirun ... < /dev/null`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I guess you mean `mpirun -n 2 script.sh`. Unfortunately, this gives the same error.

Comment: I see, you basically have one `mpirun` invoke `MPI_Init()` twice, and this is not supposed to work. A hacky way is to tweak your environment so that the first MPI program believes it was not spawned by `mpirun`. That would be implementation specific and not future proof, so you’d rather rethink how to achieve the desired outcome. Why not having `mpirun` in your script for example?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I thought so ... Well, the code is used by many people, not just me. Usage should be straightforward and intuitive. Furthermore, on some systems you have "mpirun", on others "mpiexec", on others some queueing system...
A possible (but somewhat unelegant) solution is to write a minimalistic serial program that provides the necessary data. This should work.

Comment: I found a much better solution, and a simple one. The program provides the necessary data and stops before calling `mpi_init`. So, up to that point it runs in serial.